Next static page on Vercel first load is not cached
I have some statically generated pages in my Next app (app router).
When I build the app locally, those pages are rendered immediately on navigation, as I would expect.
The same app deployed to Vercel however, the first load of those same pages are lagged, and take some 500ms to load. Only after that first render those pages are cached and render immediately.
Am I missing some cache-control configuration? I thought all this was supposed to work out of the box?
I tried going through the Next and Vercel docs on caching, but they don't seem very helpful in this case. They all say it should work out of the box with no further configuration needed.
For reference, the Cache-Control value on Vercel is public, max-age=0, must-revalidate. On localhost (running the build), it is s-maxage=31536000
